# Can we use Face ID SDK that we wrote?

Tags: ios, face-id

This is not a very technical question, sorry for that but I couldn't see any offical document about it that's why I need your help.
Does Apple reject the applications which use third party Face ID SDK which does not belongs to Apple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope your app will never rejected for using legal third party library, You can use third party which provides face detection.
I have used Luxand , also some microsoft library too for detect the face.

You can use apple vision framework. it is best to use [Learn more](https://medium.com/@kravik/ios-11-tutorial-vision-framework-3c836d5ecadd)

So you  don't need to worry about that

Comment: Thank you. But one the client that use same third party we use for Face ID SDK got rejected because of this reason. At the same time other client has approved. We are confused.
We use Daon’s IdentityX Mobile Framework/SDK.

Comment: @ondermerol There might be a another reason for same. Apple allows us to use third party library. I have personally used Luxand sdk and Microsoft Face api and apple has raise no issue

Comment: Can I ask your app name? Or other apps that use same library as you?

Comment: Thank you. Do you use it for authentication? If yes do you use remote authentication? Because there exists an Apple rule here https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments which says "2.5.13 Apps using facial recognition for account authentication must use LocalAuthentication (and not ARKit or other facial recognition technology), and must use an alternate authentication method for users under 13 years old."

Comment: @ondermerol no we are not using anything like that sorry for that